# Change ring mode for specic number/User in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-audiomanager

i want to change the ring mode for specific number. For example I saved a number

```
String Number = "12345567"
```

now on incoming call, it checks

```
if(incoming_cal-_no == Number)
{
   ring_mode = silent
}
```

i want to do some thing like that??? How can i do this????

Answer (score 0):

Create a brodcast receiver for listening to incoming calls

When you receive any incoming call parse the calling information and get the phone number

something like this

public class Telephone extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private Context mContext;
private Intent mIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mIntent = intent;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)              
             context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
    tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = 
                                            new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        String callState = "UNKNOWN";
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                            // DO YOUR WORK HERE

                 put logic to silent the phone.

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                      if(incomingNumber.length() >0){


                              // incoming call
                             // DO YOUR WORK HERE when call is received





                        }
                       else{
                                  // outgoing call
                          }
            break;
        }

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
```

}